# Windows Phone: Deployment of application to device failed. Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721800

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm developing a windows phone application on Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 virtual environment.  I've setup Visual Studio to Run as an administrator.  Every time I try to run the windows phone 7 application, it gives me this error:

Windows Phone: Deployment of application to device failed. Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721800

THe only two solutions I found so far are: run as admin (which I am doing) and delete the .user and .suo file (I deleted the project's .user file but didn't see a .suo file anywhere).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Quick google result: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/82372/497101.aspx

Comment: That caused this: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/68634.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [this archive](http://dennisdel.com/windowsphone/CoreCon.zip) (the `CoreCon` folder containing the valid datastore). Delete the contents of the 10.0 folder (leave the folder itself intact) and extract the files you just downloaded in it.

Comment: Promising, but now I'm getting "Windows Phone is doing a complete OS reboot"  why is that?

Comment: Uninstall and then install again the Windows Phone developer tools.

Comment: In the process of, I was afraid of that.  I hope this doesn't become a common occurrence.  I'm going to update this time with the january update which was missing.  Any other updates to be aware of?

Comment: Do you have an AppHub developer account? The January update is a bit, out of date, shall I say. You need to get the Mango bits already.

Comment: No, I don't have the AppHub developer account yet... Thanks.